# unable to execute pyspark after installation

Tags: java, python, apache-spark, pyspark, installation

I have manually copied the `spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz` and extracted. Then I have made entry in `.bash_profile` as below:

> export SPARK_HOME=/Users/suman/Pyspark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7
>   export PATH=$SPARK_HOME/bin:$PATH

I'm sure that i have installed `jdk.Response` below:

> ABCDEFGH:bin suman$ java -version java version "11" 2018-09-25
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11+28) Java HotSpot(TM)
>   64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11+28, mixed mode)

Error below:

> ABCDEFGH:bin suman$ pyspark

```
Python 3.7.0 (default, Jun 28 2018, 07:39:16) 
[Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:273)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.ensureInitialized(UserGroupInformation.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.loginUserFromSubject(UserGroupInformation.java:791)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getLoginUser(UserGroupInformation.java:761)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser(UserGroupInformation.java:634)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$getCurrentUserName$1.apply(Utils.scala:2422)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.getCurrentUserName(Utils.scala:2422)
    at org.apache.spark.SecurityManager.<init>(SecurityManager.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.secMgr$lzycompute$1(SparkSubmit.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$secMgr$1(SparkSubmit.scala:359)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anonfun$prepareSubmitEnvironment$7.apply(SparkSubmit.scala:367)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.prepareSubmitEnvironment(SparkSubmit.scala:366)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:143)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$2.doSubmit(SparkSubmit.scala:924)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:933)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3319)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1874)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:52)
    ... 23 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/suman/Pyspark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 38, in <module>
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/Users/suman/Pyspark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/context.py", line 298, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/Users/suman/Pyspark/spark-2.4.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 94, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Comment: Try switching to Java 8.

Comment: I have installed JDK 8 update 191 package but still the same issue.

Comment: Did you add `export JAVA_HOME=/path/to/jdk` in `.bash_profile`?

Comment: brew tap caskroom/versions and brew cask install java8 are executed for installing java 8.  then /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_192.jdk/Contents/Home path has been added to .bash_profiles and it worked.

Comment: Thank you sir @karma4917. You made my day.

Comment: No problem. Glad that it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything in the answers here including karma & suman's answers and nothing worked. I added this path to .bash_profile and it worked for me:

```
export JAVA_HOME="/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home -v 1.8"
```

I hope it works for you.