# Unable to create spark context on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark

Can anyone help me I am getting below error while creating Spark Context?
I am unable to create as i am getting the below error

```
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext

conf=SparkConf().setMaster("localhost")
sc=SparkContext(conf = conf)


ExceptionTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-3d97d6624879> in <module>()
----> 1 sc=SparkContext(conf = conf)

/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.pyc in __init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    113         """
    114         self._callsite = first_spark_call() or CallSite(None, None, None)
--> 115         SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    116         try:
    117             self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,

/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/context.pyc in _ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    296         with SparkContext._lock:
    297             if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 298                 SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    299                 SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    300 

/home/cloudera/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.pyc in launch_gateway(conf)
     92 
     93             if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
---> 94                 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
     95 
     96             with open(conn_info_file, "rb") 

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Comment: Likely wrong Java version (https://stackoverflow.com/q/53375699/6910411, https://stackoverflow.com/q/49961991) but please post full traceback, if you have one.

Comment: being a beginner i could not understand. Could you please explain in detail. @user6910411

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when your PySpark version doesn't match the Spark version you have setup. (Dictated by `SPARK_HOME` variable) - I remember this being the issue long back.

On your terminal, try doing

```
pip freeze|grep pyspark
```

And then

```
spark-shell --version
```

Make sure the versions match. If so, restart your kernel and try again. Hope this helps !